# How can I see my pc specs like this photo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, gentoo, arch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcI2m.jpg)

With this OS icon ?

Comment: what is exactly your question?

Comment: [here it is](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/master/neofetch#L5650)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking at the command neofetch: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch

which says:

> Neofetch is a command-line system information tool written in bash
>   3.2+. Neofetch displays information about your operating system, software and hardware in an aesthetic and visually pleasing way.

Installation instructions seem to be here: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Installation

Debian has a package named *screenfetch* which seems very similar; for other distributions, if not provided by the package manager, may be this page helps: http://tuxtweaks.com/2013/12/install-screenfetch-linux/